# Getting sql error PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am following a codeiniter tutorial, which tells me to make a database with the following code (using mysql):

```
 $sql = "create database login;
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_login` (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ";
```

I try to run this, using my own php code, but i keep getting this error, and have no idea how to solve it:

```
Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_login` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREM' at line 2
```

No idea what it could be.

Comment: You can't execute 2 statements at once with your PHP command.

Comment: Split it up, execute it as two statements. Or better yet, [use the migrations feature of Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html).

Comment: @tadman So you mean i have to split create database and create table?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the tutorial is. Is it publicly accessible via a link?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes it is. https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter

Comment: Umm yeah, they seem to skip over the whole how to on the database stuff... What I would suggest is that you run those manually one at a time, through something like phpmyadmin... Then I would head over to the CodeIgniter user guide - you should have a local copy of it in your CI Download, and have a read through it to see how to set the database up so you can connect to it. That'll be fun for you to do :)

Comment: If that is unclear please feel free to say so :0

Comment: @TimBrownlaw That i figured out :) .

Thanks anyway Tim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create database login;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_login` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

are two commands which are to be executed separately. Have the database created before you try to create the table - either via a SQL client or by executing something like:

```
$sql1 = 'create database login;';
$sql1->execute();

$sql2 = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_login`...';
$sql2->execute();
```